# Is there a way to share my joomla localhost website to someone else from the same network?

Tags: localhost, web-hosting

So I have this website locally. and I would like that my coworkers can look the website, we are in the same network but is there a way to host the website?

Comment: Local websites are usually available locally unless you have done something to prevent it.  Are you using a firewall?  What happens when they try to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By locally I assume you mean on your local desktop and that your coworkers are on the same campus.  To answer your question more specificaly, we would need to know what your operating system is.  However, your coworkers should be able to access the website via your IP address assuming your network administrators have not blocked it somehow.

For example, if your IP address is 10.1.2.3 then your coworkers should be able to see it via http://10.1.2.3.  In MS Windows, you can go to your command prompt and type "ipconfig" and it will give you your IP address.  I'm sure there's an equivalent command in your specific operating system.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me no problem if the site is up and running (web server) The site can be made accesible internally and externally if the reference and port(s) to the (web) site are open, are passed on by the router. example: ip 123.12.32.1:80
Even in the case of another network / subnet, a connection via local host can be made through a ssh tunnel. I prefer to use an ssh tunnel myself. The access must be arranged in the firewall. ssh port 80 to 123.12.32.1:80 then the website can be accessed with "localhost" only afte connection throug the tunnel is made.